# The fixed navbar overlaps content in small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have copied the code so i dont have much idea bout it.The design seems to work fine in desktop browsers but as soon as i use mobile configurations the footer seems to overlap the content..

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom container">
    <div class="row">

    <div>
      <p class="navbar-text"  align="center">© 
      <script type="text/javascript">
                document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
            </script>   
           mywebsite.com
      </p>
    </div>



    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

body { padding-top: 15px;}
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        body { padding-top: 0px; }
        body { padding-bottom: 60px; }
    }
```

Here is the footer class..

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: share your link

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrap the whole nav in a

div class='container'